# i feel like i got this wrong

Tags: sql, database, oracle

The commission classification column should be able to store integers up to a maximum value of 99 and be named `Comm_id`. The value of the `Comm_id` column should be set to a value of 10 automatically if no value is provided when a row is added. The benefits code column should also accommodate integer values up to a maximum of 99 and be named `Ben_id`.

```
alter table ACCTMANAGER 
add (Comm_id varchar2(99), 
Ben_id varchar2(99));
```

I dont know if this is right

Comment: if commission & benefits are integer, why are you creating a varchar column? the maximum values can easily be managed with a check constraint

Comment: And, you have no DEFAULT value on the `Comm_id` column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

alter table ACCTMANAGER add(Comm_id number(2) default 10, Ben_id number(2));

Basically for number data type you have precision and scale. and if scale is not specified scale is 0 which means no decimal places after the number. number(2) means you can only store up to two digit number here and default keyword set the value automatically if column was not specified.

BTW try using oracle documentation for this homework type of stuff. here is with good examples.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209

**EDITED**
alter table ACCTMANAGER add(Comm_id number(2) default 10 constraint lowchk1 check(comm_id>=0) , Ben_id number(2) constraint lowchk2 check(ben_id>=0));

Sorry I can't check syntax for sure as I don't have Oracle installed at home. I only work at it at office.

Comment: This answer may help, but it is not actually correct. It allows the insertion of negative numbers (up to -99), and also fractional numbers such as 2.2; Oracle will silently truncate that to 2 and store 2 in the base table.

Comment: you can easily add check constraint for limiting number to positive value, and I am not sure how you are wanting to handle the rounding of value, oracle will truncate the value if it is lower than 0,5 and will round up the value if it 0.5 or higher...

Comment: I already showed how to check that a number is an integer in my solution; you check that the number is equal to its truncation.

Comment: Yah sorry too early in the morning for me didn't read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

@MSStp provided a good answer, but you still need constraints to make sure you don't get bad data in the table (such as negative numbers). If the constraint is that the commission and the benefit columns must contain integers between 0 and 99, and you want to make sure Oracle will not accept an input of 2.2 (which it WILL accept in MS's solution, it will just truncate it to 2 and store 2 in the database), you need to add constraints as Abdul Rehman Sayed suggested in a Comment to your question.

```
alter table acctmanager
    add ( comm_id number(2) default 10 
                    constraint check_comm ( comm_id >= 0 and comm_id = trunc(comm_id) ),
          ben_id  number(2) 
                    constraint check_ben  ( ben_id  >= 0 and ben_id  = trunc(ben_id) )
        )
;
```

**However**: Just a thought.....  What are `comm_id` and `ben_id`? If they are some sort of codes to specific commission and benefit descriptions/levels/whatever, do you really need check constraints? Do you have different tables explaining these codes, where `comm_id` and `ben_id` are (or should be) primary keys? In which case you need foreign key constraints, NOT check constraints?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE ACCTMANGER ADD(Comm_id NUMBER(2) DEFAULT 10 NOT NULL, Ben_id NUMBER(2));
```

After that, you can see that the table is altered.

To see the Output write this:

```
DESC ACCTMANAGER;
```

You will see the whole table with the updated column.